# How to stop spam registrations?

Tags: php, spam, spam-prevention

We have a website that allows people to register once per IP address or email address. If our system detects a second registration by the same IP address or email address, it blocks it.

In our registration form, I use reCAPATCHA. However, some spammers are still able to get through -- they are cycling through multiple different IPs and email addresses.

Anyway for me to stop this? We use PHP to power our form and website.

Comment: I think blocking an ip is not a good idea. for example in case of a public wifi, many users may use it. But the ip will be same for all requests from the modem

Comment: @jophab I know. However, I have no other way to do it.

Comment: Have you tried doing a form token that will check against a session token?

Comment: try email verification. As we do while registering in stack overflow and other famous sites

Comment: @jophab We already do email verification.